# ValueError: object too deep for desired array, when I try to use scipy's convolve2d method

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Here's the code:

```
x = range(-6,7)
tmp1 = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    tmp1.append(math.exp(-(i*i)/(2*self.sigma*self.sigma)))
max_tmp1 = max(tmp1)
mod_tmp1 = []
for i in range(len(tmp1)):
    mod_tmp1.append(max_tmp1 - i)
ht1 = np.kron(np.ones((9,1)),tmp1)
sht1 = sum(ht1.flatten(1))
mean = sht1/(13*9)
ht1 = ht1 - mean
ht1 = ht1/sht1
print ht1.shape
h = np.zeros((16,16))
for i in range(0, 9):
    for j in range(0, 13):
        h[i+3, j+1] = ht1[i, j]

for i in range(0, 10):
    ag = 15*i
    np.append(h, scipy.misc.imrotate(h, ag, 'bicubic'))

R = []
print h.shape
print self.img.shape
for i in range(0, 11):
    print 'here'
    R[i] = scipy.signal.convolve2d(self.img, h[i], mode = 'same')

rt = np.zeros(self.img.shape)
x, y = self.img.shape
```

The error I get states:

> ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array

Comment: self refers to the instance attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if the problem is that you're setting `h` up wrongly. I assume you want `h[i]` to be a 16x16 array suitable for convolving with, but that's not what you've actually made it, for a couple of different reasons.

I suggest you change the loop with the `imrotate` calls to this:

```
h = [scipy.misc.imrotate(h, 15*i, 'bicubic') for i in range(10)]
```

(What your existing code does is: first set up `h` as a single 16x16 array; then, repeatedly: compute a rotated version, "flatten" both `h` and that to make 256-element vectors, compute the result of appending them to make a 512-element vector, and throw the result away. `numpy.append` doesn't operate in place, and defaults to flattening its arguments before it appends. Neither of those is what you want!)

The list comprehension above will give you a 10-element Python list containing rotated versions of your convolution kernel.

... Oh, I see that your loop computing `R` actually wants 11 kernels, not 10. Make it `range(11)`, then. (Your original code generated rotations of 0, 0, 15, 30, ..., 135 degrees, but I'm guessing 0, 15, 30, ..., 150 degrees is more likely to be what you want.)

Comment: I now get IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: I get the error mentioned in my previous comment when convoluting.

Comment: Did you replace `range(10)` with `range(11)` as I suggested in my last paragraph?

Comment: (Because that IndexError is exactly what I'd expect you to get if you didn't.)

Comment: Yes, I did. I get the indexerror with both; 11 and 10.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see what's happened. You're trying to assign to elements of `R` that aren't there yet. Use `R.append(scipy.signal.convolve(...))` instead of `R[i] = ...`. (Perhaps you're used to something like MATLAB that auto-creates array elements when you assign to them?)

Comment: You're absolutely right. numpy arrays are very new to me, and I'm still learning. Thanks a lot!